# Maven will not compile project with module-info. Having 'cannot find symbol' and 'javafx package XY does not exist'

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-module, module-info

I am trying tu run `mvn clean compile` on my Eclipse project with `module-info.java` present. However the build ends up with many errors like:

`package javafx.XY does not exist` (All referring to JavaFX packages) and

`can not find symbol` ... (All referring to JavaFX classes).

Example of error output (Whole is not necessary. There are no other types of errors):

```
[ERROR] /home/gitrow/Desktop/ispf-new/ispf/desktop.common/src/main/java/desktop/controller/registry/Registry.java:[82,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
[ERROR]   location: class desktop.controller.registry.Registry
[ERROR] /home/gitrow/Desktop/ispf-new/ispf/desktop.common/src/main/java/desktop/controller/registry/AbstractTableViewController.java:[3,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /home/gitrow/Desktop/ispf-new/ispf/desktop.common/src/main/java/desktop/controller/registry/Registry.java:[185,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ActionEvent
[ERROR]   location: class desktop.controller.registry.Registry
```

Without `module-info.java`, running `mvn clean compile` ends up with success.

All packages from my project are 'exported'. All javafx packages are 'required':

module-info:

```
module desktop.common
{
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    requires transitive javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;

    requires java.persistence;

    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires org.hibernate.commons.annotations;

    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;

    requires java.sql;

    requires com.github.albfernandez.javadbf;

    exports desktop.controller.otherstages;
    exports desktop.controller.registry;
    exports desktop.entities;
    exports desktop.core;
    exports desktop.other;
    exports desktop.exceptions;
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>registry</groupId>
    <artifactId>desktop.common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.albfernandez</groupId>
            <artifactId>javadbf</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Does anyone know what might cause mvn compile not ending up with success with that module-info? (I also tried creating project once more, cleaning, mvn update, making javafx dependencies as not 'optional' in pom).

Using Eclipse 06-2021 and Temurin 11 JDK (new AdoptOpenJDK) (Also does not work with AdoptOpenJDK 16, so there is no problem in JDK)